# Can I use pattern matching both by class and variable?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Consider the following example:

```
def combine(trees: List[CodeTree]): List[CodeTree] =
  if (trees.isEmpty || singleton(trees)) trees
  else trees match {
    case Leaf(cl, wl) :: Leaf(cr, wr) :: tail =>
      Fork(new Leaf(cl, wl), new Leaf(cr, wr), List(cl, cr), wl + wr) :: tail
  }
```

I would like to know whether I could capture the two `Leaf` instances into a variable. I would expect a syntax like the following:

```
def combine(trees: List[CodeTree]): List[CodeTree] =
  if (trees.isEmpty || singleton(trees)) trees
  else trees match {
    case l: Leaf(cl, wl) :: r: Leaf(cr, wr) :: tail =>
      Fork(l, r, List(cl, cr), wl + wr) :: tail
  }
```

This does not actually compile, but I was hoping for something similar.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use colon for types, so you'd have to write something like this:

```
case (l: Leaf[???]) :: (r: Leaf[???]) :: tail =>
```

But there's a way to match a pattern and extract it at the same time, which is using the "at" sign:

```
case (l @ Leaf(cl, wl)) :: (r @ Leaf(cr, wr)) :: tail =>
```

PS: I have no idea where parenthesis are necessary, so I added them anyway.

Comment: Looks like you need the parens because the var binds either simple pattern or infix (sp op sp).

Comment: Yes, the parentheses are required. It works! Thanks!